# Can not drag-drop or copy-paste files between guest and host

Tags: qemu, spice

The [documentation](https://www.spice-space.org/spice-user-manual.html) says:

> Installing the Spice vdagent in your guest will let you copy and paste
> between your guest and client OSes, to drag and drop files between the
> 2 OSes, … In order for the agent to work, your virtual machine must
> have a virtio serial device (and the corresponding guest drivers) as
> well as a Spice spicevmc channel.

It also says:

> Agent support allows better integration with the guest. For example,
> it allows copy and paste between the guest and the host OSes, dynamic
> resolution changes when the client window is resized/full-screened,
> file transfers through drag and drop, …
>
> The agent is a daemon/service running in the guest OS so it must be
> installed if it was not installed by default during the guest OS
> installation. It also relies on a virtio-serial PCI device and a
> dedicated spicevmc char device to achieve communication between the
> guest and the host. These devices must be added to the virtual machine
> for the agent to work in the guest.

I have installed all the necessities in the guest. And then enabled the services.

```
sudo apt install qemu-guest-agent spice-vdagent spice-webdavd

sudo systemctl start spice-vdagent
sudo systemctl enable spice-vdagent

sudo systemctl start qemu-guest-agent
sudo systemctl enable qemu-guest-agent

sudo systemctl start spice-webdavd
sudo systemctl enable spice-webdavd
```

Started the vm with the following script.

```
#!/bin/bash

QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=spice

qemu-system-x86_64 -accel kvm,thread=multi -cpu host -smp 2 -m 8192 \
-drive file=/media/ismail/SSDWorking/_QEMU/vm_mint.qcow2,format=qcow2,if=virtio \
-machine vmport=off \
-vga virtio -usb -device qemu-xhci -device usb-tablet \
-soundhw hda \
-spice port=5911,addr=127.0.0.1,disable-ticketing \
-device virtio-serial-pci \
-chardev spicevmc,id=spicechannel0,debug=0,name=vdagent \
-device virtserialport,chardev=spicechannel0,name=com.redhat.spice.0 \
-device virtserialport,chardev=charchannel1,id=channel1,name=org.spice-space.webdav.0 \
-chardev spiceport,name=org.spice-space.webdav.0,id=charchannel1 \
-chardev socket,path=/tmp/qga.sock,server=on,wait=off,id=qga0 \
-device virtio-serial \
-device virtserialport,chardev=qga0,name=org.qemu.guest_agent.0 \
-daemonize

remote-viewer --spice-shared-dir=/media/ismail/SSDWorking/_QEMU/VM_Share spice://127.0.0.1:5911 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Now  dynamic resolution changes work. However, drag and drop and copy-paste files between guest and host does not work.

Just to be clear, copy-paste text between guest and host works. Drag and drop text between guest and host does not work. In the case of files, neither copy-paste nor drag and drop work.

What might be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP Here, What I thought is, the file will be where I dropped the file. But what I found is with my given config, if I drag a file from host to guest then a folder open in the explorer and the dragged file is there.

drag&drop from host to guest works, not the opposite.

In the guest, where the file will be saved can be set using:

```
$ spice-vdagent --help
....
  -f, --file-xfer-save-dir=<dir|xdg-desktop|xdg-download>     Set directory to file transfers files
  -o, --file-xfer-open-dir=<0|1>                              Open directory after completing file transfer
```

Here, the value of `-o` is 0 or 1.